# Question on notation of 3rd degree Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, integral-equations

Let $\;f \in C^3(\mathbb R^m;\mathbb R)\;$ and $\;g,h:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m\;$ be two smooth functions.

> If $\;I(h)=f(g+h)-f(g)-Df(g)\cdot h-\frac{1}{2}D^2(f(g))h \cdot h\;$ then it
>   follows $\;I(h)=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} p^2 l
>  D^3(f(g+klph))(h,h,h)\;dp\;dl\;dk\;$

*NOTE:* $\;h \cdot h\;$ is the $\;L^2-$inner product.

However I 'm having a really hard time understanding what exactly $\;(h,h,h)\;$ represents here

Any help here would be valuable! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Actually for $D^{3}$, it is a map that $D^{3}:{\bf{R}}^{n}\rightarrow L({\bf{R}}^{n},L({\bf{R}}^{n},L({{\bf{R}}^{n}},{\bf{R}}^{m})))\cong L({\bf{R}}^{n}\times{\bf{R}}^{n}\times{\bf{R}}^{n},{\bf{R}}^{m})$, so we can input three $h\in{\bf{R}}^{n}$ to $D^{3}(a)$, that is, $D^{3}(a)(h,h,h)$ makes sense.

Comment: Excuse me if I sound silly but what is $\;(h,h,h)\;$ then? Is it some kind of product? I would appreciate if you could give me more details

Comment: It is not a product, it is the $3$-tuple with each $h$ in coordinates, this is just like $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z$ and maybe you put $f(1,2,3)=1+2+3$, the $3$-tuple $(1,2,3)$. Of course, here $h$ is itself in $n$-dimensional. In a sense, $(x,y,z)$ for each $x,y,z\in{\bf{R}}^{n}$ is $(u_{1},...,u_{n},u_{n+1},...,u_{2n},u_{2n+1},...,u_{3n})$ if you string out all the components, so it is ${\bf{R}}^{n}$.